# PostgreSQL: 'FATAL: role "*" does not exist' while connecting from application

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, privileges

PostgreSQL suddenly raising 'role does not exists' after few months of excelent work.
I can see this error when trying to connect from application but 'psql' works fine:

```
07:43:16.700 [postgresql connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - postgresql - Cannot acquire connection from data source
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: role "user" does not exist
...
lalala@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal:~$ docker exec -it postgresql psql -U user db;
psql (9.6.1)
Type "help" for help.

db=>
```

Does anyone know what may cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If it has been working then it's a bit odd, I would check the date on your pg_hba.conf file and recent changes. Within that file your psql (local) will be a different setting which could explain why there is a difference in behaviour